# Excel VBA, Worksheet.Change for 3 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have three cells, and these are interdependent in the following way:

If I know the value of two of them, then I can compute the value of the remaining one. In other words, if my three cells are A1, A2, A3,

- I can compute the value in A3 from A1 and A2,
- I can compute the value in A2 from A1 and A3,
- and I can compute the value in A1 from A2 and A3.

My goal is to obtain a worksheet that does the following:

- If I change the value in A1 and A2 (in any order), then the value in A3 is computed,
- If I change the value in A1 and A3 (in any order), then the value in A2 is computed,
- And finally, if I change the value in A2 and A3 (in any order), then the value in A1 is computed.

If there were only two cells, then I would know how to use `Worksheet.Change` in order to obtain something similar. Similarly, if the values in the two cells were changed simultaneously, then I would also know how to obtain something satisfying.

However, in my case, the changes are successive and not simultaneous, so that I have no idea how to implement it, since `Worksheet.Change` only works for one target.

Comment: I could think of multiple ways to go about it. (1) use the worksheet change event to see if two cells are filled and thus allow you to calculate the third cell (2) keep track (with some kind of a timestamp) when the user changed which cell and always calculate the third cell based on the two cells which have been changed last (3) use a `userform` instead. With option buttons, check-boxes and multiple events on each text-box there is yet another multitude of ways to go about this. So, to me (personally) the question is actually at bit too broad to answer (as it stands right now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to track the change status of your three cells, and act when two have changed, like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static TrackChange As Integer

    On Error GoTo EH
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(1, 1)) Is Nothing Then
        TrackChange = TrackChange Or 1 ' Set bit 0
    End If
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(2, 1)) Is Nothing Then
        TrackChange = TrackChange Or 2 ' Set bit 1
    End If
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(3, 1)) Is Nothing Then
        TrackChange = TrackChange Or 4 ' Set bit 2
    End If
    Debug.Print TrackChange
    Select Case TrackChange
        Case 3 ' A1, A2 changed
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ' update A3
            Me.Cells(3, 1) = Me.Cells(1, 1) + Me.Cells(2, 1)
            TrackChange = 0
        Case 5 ' A1, A3 changed
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ' update A2
            Me.Cells(2, 1) = Me.Cells(1, 1) + Me.Cells(3, 1)
            TrackChange = 0
        Case 6 ' A2, A3 changed
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ' update A1
            Me.Cells(1, 1) = Me.Cells(2, 1) + Me.Cells(3, 1)
            TrackChange = 0
        Case 7 ' A1, A2, A3 changed
            TrackChange = 0
    End Select
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer. I wasn't aware of the behavior of [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251620.aspx) or that it is possible to retain a variable's value between two procedure calls.

Comment: Nice! You should add `Case 7 TrackChange = 0`. If you don't, your code will stop working after changing all 3 cells once.